# How to compare two spatial points patterns in R?

Tags: r, distributions, spatial

I have two spatial points data sets (relocations of animal A and distribution of plant B). How can I investigate if animal A is more likely to be where plant B is present?

With the animal relocations I calculated its utilization distribution (UD) with KernelUD() from Adehabitat package, however I do not know how to compare it with the plant locations. If easier I could simply compare the two spatial points data sets, however I`m not sure how to do it either way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any legitimate, objective answer to this question *must* be based on an understanding of how those "relocations" occurred and how the data were collected.  Could you explain what a relocation is and how the points in the datasets were obtained or measured?

Comment: They are GPS points of locations/relocations of the same animal, that is, I followed the animal and kept getting points in the GPS.

Comment: Is it one animal or many?  How do you intend to interpret "more likely": do you wish to make a statement about this animal's general behavior, about its behavior only while you were tracking it, or perhaps about the behavior of other animals like it?

Comment: Hey _whuber_ it`s just one animal and I want to make statements about its behavior only while I`m tracking it. I basically want to check if I have more GPS points of the animal in places where there is more GPS points of the plant B (i.e., trees). Thanks a lot.

Comment: That seems ridiculously simple: count your points!  It seems you aren't asking for a statistical inference (in the sense of testing "more likely"), but only a description of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Using the original point patterns, a bivariate (or cross) version of Ripley's K seems appropriate. See this encyclopedia entry, [Dixon (2012)](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~pdixon/stat406/RipleyK.pdf), for a good overview.

Here is an example in R using the *spatstat* package. In a nutshell, Ripley's K counts the number of pairwise comparisons within a certain distance, and then divides by the overall density of one of the point patterns. In the case of homogeneous Poisson processes we know the expected value of this function, and so if the observed Ripley's K value is above the expected function, the two point patterns might be attracted to one one another.

```
library(spatstat)
set.seed(3)
X <- rmpoint(200,types=c('A','B'),ptypes=c(0.5,0.5))
ripK <- Kcross(X)
plot(ripK)
```

[image]

(This plot includes several different types of border corrections for the values, which may or may not be applicable for your particular application.)