# How can I run stats on 2D data?

Tags: distributions, spatial

For example, I have a collection of 2D points (x and y) on a 10x10 grid. What can I use to test if the points are from a uniform distribution (randomly distributed)? What can I use to see if they are from the same distribution as another set of points?

Comment: [Ripley's K](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163535/1036) is one potential test. This can be for to test for complete spatial randomness in one point pattern. Or if you have multiple point patterns can be used to see if they are clustered with one another or repelled from one another.

Comment: To clarify: is the location of each point defined solely as being in one of the 100 boxes in a 10x10 grid, or are point positions defined over a continuous but restricted space? Also, about how many points are you considering in your test set and in the set against you wish to compare?